# How does Mediation Analysis Account for Covariates

Tags: regression, spss, mediation

Can anyone explain how mediation analysis accounts for covariates?

For example, when I run a simple mediation analysis with X predicting Y mediated with M -- what happens when I specificy PROCESS macro from SPSS or R package that I have a covariate? Thank you